# How to switch between copy-constructor and default constructor depending on argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I have the following code:

```
struct S
{
    S(): a(42) {}
    int a;
};

class P
{
public:
    P(S const *s): m_s(s ? *s : /*init m_s by default ctor - how to achieve it?*/)
private:
    S m_s;
};
```

I want `m_s` to be initialized either by copy-constructor or by default constructor, depending on pointer `s`:

```
P p1(nullptr); // expect default ctor: p1.m_s.a = 42
S s;
s.a = 84;
P p2(&s); // expect copy ctor: p2.m_s.a = 84
```

How can I do it in a most elegant way?

Comment: Try this: `m_s(s ? *s : S())`. Not most efficient, but that's the price you pay for using pointers.

Comment: You probably can't do it in a "most elegant way." Many non-elegant solutions are equally contending for the first place.

Comment: @n.m. Why is that not the most efficient? I would expect the compiler to optimize away any unnecessary copies.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I don't think the compiler will optimize out explicitly invoked copy constructors. Not sure if it's allowed.

Comment: @n.m. It is allowed, and will be optimized out. Demo: http://goo.gl/XpVzVG

Comment: @T.C. thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write:

```
class P {
public:
    P(S const *s): m_s(s ? *s : S()){}
private:
    S m_s;
};
```

You might find it more elegant to extract the conditional to a separate helper function:

```
S createS(S const *s) {
  return s ? *s : S();
}
```

This may look like it will perform an unnecessary copy in the case of a `nullptr` argument but in practice the compiler will perform RVO and optimize out the copy.

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/G1r6iPeY28mn0BeM)

Comment: @Nick: This is the better solution, you should accept this one.

Comment: What actually looks like an unnecessary copy to me is the copy from `*s`, because your conditional expression is an rvalue (unlike `*s`) -- but that one too is elided :-)

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution that works only with null pointer constants would be to add an overload:

```
P(std::nullptr_t) : m_s() {}
P(const S * s) : m_s(AssertNotNull(s)) {}
```

Here I used:

```
template <typename T> T * AssertNotNull(T * p) {
  if (!p) std::abort();
  return p;
}
```

If you need a dynamic switch, you could use a helper function:

```
struct P {
  static const S & maybe(const S * s) {
    static S x;
    return s ? *s : x;
  }

  P(const S * s) : m_s(maybe(s)) {}

  S m_s;
}
```

This doesn't actually switch between copy and default constructor (since you cannot do that dynamically), but it fakes the effect by copying from a default-constructed instance if the pointer is null.

Comment: Why return by reference from `maybe`? If you return by value the compiler will optimize away any copy and you won't need that troubling static variable. In fact, when [I test it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BbsUWMFdg32rD5oo), that static variable is actually defeating RVO and causing an extra copy.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Yes, that's also a possibility.